# Using SQL cursors instead of self-join to find non - consecutive numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

In SQL Server, I would like to check if numbers in a specific column are following each other in ascending order using SQL Cursor Functions. Basically each row must have a greater value than the previous one. I have written a code using **self-join** as shown below:

First I have given each row a row number that is defined as integer, in order to compare each row with the previous one using `select row_number() over(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) AS Row#`. Then compared the table with itself using the row number created above and found the rows that are not consecutive using the code below.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM Sequence AS prev_row
  JOIN Sequence AS next_row 
  ON prev_row.Row#+1 = next_row.Row#
  AND (prev_row.Number > next_row.Number)
```

Even though my code above is working fine, I wanted to perform the same operation using SQL Cursors to have a better understanding of usage of cursors and develop a different approach on SQL methods. So I wrote the following code, but it is not working:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR 
FOR
SELECT Row#, Number
FROM Sequence;

DECLARE @Row# int;
DECLARE @Numbers int;

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @Row# , @Numbers
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
    SELECT @Row#, @Numbers --this part is for printing results
    where @Row#>@Row#+1 --condition
END
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Can someone explain where I go wrong? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with cursor. It probably misses `FETCH NEXT ... INTO <list of vars>` part and `ORDER BY` in cursor declaration.

Comment: In fact you're not checking nothing, only fetching rows.

Comment: Several problems.  You have proved nothing about compare with previous as a table is not ordered.   In the cursor you don't fetch a single row and even fail to fetch.  Sql has a lag function.

Comment: I am trying to check if `@Row#>@Row#+1`.

Comment: Can someone show an example of or redirect me to the example of fetching rows from a table and selecting from fetched result set?

Comment: MSDN does have examples of CURSOR declaration and usage.

Comment: I have checked many of them but could not apply to my question. But for sure will check it again.

Comment: On a sidenote: Such task would usually be solved with `LAG` or `LEAD`.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't heard of LAG or LEAD before, but after some research, they seemed really suitable for such task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> create table seq(id int, val int);
> insert into seq values
> (1,  10),
> (2,  11),
> (3,  15),
> (4,  20),
> (5,  19),
> (6,  24),
> (7,  30),
> (8,  31),
> (9,  29),
> (10, 35);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 10 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select id, val,
>        iif(coalesce(lag(val) over (order by id), val) <= val, 'OK', 'ERROR') [check]
> from seq
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val | check
> -: | --: | :----
>  1 |  10 | OK   
>  2 |  11 | OK   
>  3 |  15 | OK   
>  4 |  20 | OK   
>  5 |  19 | ERROR
>  6 |  24 | OK   
>  7 |  30 | OK   
>  8 |  31 | OK   
>  9 |  29 | ERROR
> 10 |  35 | OK
> ```

> ```
> declare cur cursor for
>     select id, val from seq order by id;
>
> declare @id int = 0,
>         @val int = 0,
>         @last_val int = null;
>
> declare @res table (id int, val int, [check] varchar(10));
>
> open cur;
>
> fetch next from cur into @id, @val
>
> while @@fetch_status = 0
> begin
>     insert into @res
>     select @id, @val, iif (@last_val is null or @last_val < @val, 'OK', 'ERROR');
>
>     set @last_val = @val;    
>
>     fetch next from cur into @id, @val;
> end
>
> close cur;
> deallocate cur;
>
> select * from @res;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val | check
> -: | --: | :----
>  1 |  10 | OK   
>  2 |  11 | OK   
>  3 |  15 | OK   
>  4 |  20 | OK   
>  5 |  19 | ERROR
>  6 |  24 | OK   
>  7 |  30 | OK   
>  8 |  31 | OK   
>  9 |  29 | ERROR
> 10 |  35 | OK
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8acc191342fbc6f3440a8d894ef2a314)*

Comment: Thank you Sir, it is working. By the way since `iff` is not supported by versions older than 2012 like mine,  `select @id, @val, iif (@last_val is null or @last_val < @val, 'OK', 'ERROR');` part should be changed as:  `CASE WHEN (@last_val IS NULL or @last_val < @val )
    THEN 'OK' 
    ELSE 'FALSE'
    END` I believe.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You should tag your sql server version in your questions.